# Dynamic creation of PeriodicTasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I have found [this soultion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/celery-users/CZXCh8sCK5Q/ihZgMV2HWWYJ) for adding periodic task schedules dynamically with `django-celery`.
My use case is mailings, which being added individually for users of web-site, each mailing has a `PeriodicTask` associated with it, so there is potentially may be huge quantity of `PeriodicTask` records in DB.

Im interested - is it valid (legal, proper, right) solution in that case, or it is better to have only one or few `PeriodicTask`'s which would check mailings for last time they been sent and send them if necessary?

Answer (score 2):

According to it's creator, Ask Solem [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/celery-users/mXij8Dd-i6Y/n4PC8HHBF4gJ):

> There is no known limit to the number of periodic tasks, and the celerybeat scheduler should perform well even with a large number of schedule entries.

[That Google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/mXij8Dd-i6Y) and [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/mXij8Dd-i6Y) are the most clarifying about the concern you have.

Said that, I'd like to give you an advice: even when celerybeat scheduler is able to handle huge amounts of periodical tasks, that will come to a cost: more database entries, more tasks to monitor, more ram, maybe more complexity for debugging because you are creating dynamic tasks, more hits to database because you will have to check for each mailing its sent datetime and then see if you send that email.

On the other hand, if you can have one one periodical task that can do one query to retrieve just the mailing instances that have to be sent and the fire one subtask task per email you have to send, then it would look simpler in your code, when you have to debug it and when you have to monitor it. Just my two cents.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not have a single periodic task which runs every day, week or whatever, and inside that calculate in the first part all the users which require mailings at that time? Once you know all of these, you could kick-off a sub-task in celery for each of these so that these are all executed asynchronously and will allow the main task to complete very quickly, e.g.

```
@task
def send_periodic_emails():
    users_who_need_mail = get_users_who_need_mail()

    for user in users_who_need_mail:
        send_user_email.delay(user.id)

@task
def send_user_email(user_id):
    # Do email sending here
```

I appreciate this doesn't answer the question as it's formed, but it should allow you to avoid finding out whether this limit exists or adding scheduled tasks programatically!

Comment: Yeah, when I asked the question - becaue I had this alternative in mind. Main argument against it - because its like building another scheduler on top of Celery =)

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the nature of your work. If you can group your users into classes for mailing purposes then it would seem natural to schedule mailing of the groups rather than mailing the individual users. If everyone is on a different schedule then by all means schedule each one individually. It's certainly legal and there's no compelling reason to avoid it if it's the natural solution to your problems.

You may want to run some tests to get an idea of the load you will generate, but your approach doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: Main my concern is - is it valid use of Celery - to create thousands `PeriodicTask`'s